# Is there an alternate version of XMouseButtonControl for Linux?

Tags: mouse, alternative, remapping

This program is extremelly useful, I started using Linux only 1 day ago and I'm already missing it.
I used to hold the 2nd thumb button to use multimedia shortcuts, like volume+/-, next/previous music, mute, pause/unpause, etc... only with the mouse
Is there a Linux program to remapping mouse buttons?

Answer (score 0):

go to

system settings --> keyboard --> shortcuts

click the media functions you want to change and then hit the button on the mouse you want to assign it to. had this setup on my old logitech G400...

Comment: No, like I said, I used to combine the 2nd thumb button and the other buttons to create shortcuts, this doesn't work in system settings.

Comment: To be more clear: when I press the left button, it performs a click, but when I press 2nd thumb button+left button, it goes to the next music.

Comment: @ColdLucas I thought you would click on button 3 or 4 for next/previous song, and something simple like that... the GUI doesn't support left click, but you can probably enter it manually, just don't have time to locate where that is right now...